# Как получить ключи через DbConnection.GetSchema?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Есть провайдер, который возвращает абстрактные фабрики => мне приходится работать с экземпляром `DbConnection`.

Через `conn.GetSchema("Tables", new[] { null, null, null, "Table" })` я успешно получаю таблицы, а через `conn.GetSchema("Columns")` - все колонки и для полного счастья мне не хватает возможности получить первичные ключи.

Гуглил гуглил и не нашел решения, кроме как уйти от абстракции и работать напрямую через `GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys, null)`.

Какие варианты решения проблемы есть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используем [DataTableReader.GetSchemaTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable?view=netcore-3.1)

```
using DbConnection conn = ...;
conn.Open();
                
using DbCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "select * from TableName"; // имя нужной таблицы

// CommandBehavior.KeyInfo - получаем только информацию
using DbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Дальше из DataTable получаем ключи:

```
var keys = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<bool>("IsKey"))
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName"));

foreach (string key in keys)
    Console.WriteLine(key);
```

Смотрим все полученные данные:

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(col.ColumnName + " = " + row[col]);
}
```

---

Решение подсмотрел [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d58687c9-bb35-4f5f-ba81-52cd7fceab70/getschema-and-primarykeys-getting-primary-key-column-name?forum=adodotnetdataproviders).

Проверил на Sql Server и Sqlite - работает.